# $n$-th cohomology of locally compact subsets in R^n

Tags: reference-request, at.algebraic-topology, cohomology

Where can I find a reference that for any locally compact (or just open) subset $U$ of $\mathbb{R}^n$, $H^n(U;\mathbb{Z})$ (the n-th Cech integral cohomology) is trivial?

Answer (score 2):

You can find it in Godement Topologie Algebrique et theorie des faisceaux page 237 or Demailly Complex Analytic Geometry page 235